# Using THREE.Gyroscope to keep an object facing the camera

Tags: three.js

I've been trying to get my head around how the Chrome 100,000 Stars experiment uses [THREE.Gyroscope](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/extras/core/Gyroscope.js) to keep an object facing the camera ([as mentioned here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/casestudies/100000stars/)).

I can't find any simple examples or documentation of THREE.Gyroscope with it working.

I'm sure it's a simple thing to implement but I just can't work out how to create a gyro and have it keep a specified object facing the camera.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`var gyro = new THREE.Gyroscope();` - declare a gyroscope

`gyro.position.set(x,y,z);` - set the initial position of the gyroscope

`gyro.scale.set(x,y,z);` - the scale. It changes the size of the gyroscope i.e. when using the gyroscope for following an object, the gyroscope zooms from a closer point to the object when we set the scale less than 1.
Experiment with the above two quantities to adjust the starting point and zooming range of the gyroscope.

`scene.add(gyro);`

`gyro.add(camera);`  -  attach the camera to the gyroscope

`specificObject.add(gyro);`  -  attach the gyroscope to the object we want to keep in front

`gyro.remove(camera)` - when you're done making the camera follow that object